# Why have the web reference files changed from Reference.vb to Reference.vb.dll?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a WebForms project in VB, with a web reference to a service also in VB. I made some changes to the service and updated web reference in my WebForm, and each reference has changed to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This file is automatically generated by Visual Studio .Net. It is 
    used to store generic object data source configuration information.  
    Renaming the file extension or editing the content of this file may   
    cause the file to be unrecognizable by the program.
-->
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="Blog" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>#####, Web References.DataService.Reference.vb.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

Note the .vb.dll, this used to be just a .vb file.

Since there area 200+ of these references I want to be sure if it is safe to push them up onto the source control, as I don't want to break everything for anyone else.

We recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015 so I'm thinking that might have something else to do with it, but any help would be appreciated.

Basically, is it safe to overwrite the current web references

- `References.DataService.Reference.vb` with
- `References.DataService.Reference.vb.dll`

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or revert the file changes and see if that broke anything?